# Export C++ Solution into a .lib file and use it into another project

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, static-libraries, .lib

I have a C++ Windows Solution in Visual Studio 2019. I set the `Configuration Properties > General > Configuration Type` value into `Static library (.lib)` and then Build my solution. This generated me a `.lib` file, which I suppose I will have to link in my other solution.

My problem appears when I try to link my Static library in the new solution through `Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Dependencies` (the path) and also `Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies` (libraryName.lib).

The files inside the new solution don't detect the headers inside the Static library. Can someone guide me into linking this file?

Comment: "_don't detect the headers inside the Static library_" - There are no headers inside the static library. The header files (`.h` / `.hpp`) are to be provided along with the `.lib` and `#include`ed by the programmer using the library.

Comment: Oh!! I see, thanks for your comment.